# what is different between promise vs async when I use redux-thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

Hi I'm little bit confused how redux thunk works..
for example,

this code is work

code1

```
export const getAllUsers = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      dispatch({ type: GET_ALL_USER, payload: res.data.data });
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};
```

but this code is not working...

code2

```
export const fetchComments = () => () => {
  axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
    .then((res) => {
      return {
        type: FETCH_COMMENTS,
        payload: res.data,
      };
    });
};
```

but this code is works..

code3

```
 export const fetchComments = async() => {
     let res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
     return {
         type: FETCH_COMMENTS,
         payload:res.data
       }
   ;
 };
```

so I really wonder why code2 is not working and why code3 is works.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/async%20&%20performance/README.md#you-dont-know-js-async--performance) helps, there is no way you can dispatch the result of code 3 because a thunk needs the action to be a function and not a promise. code 2 and 3 are more or less the same if you redefine code 2 as: `fetchComments = () => axios.get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Why is Code #1 working? - Dispatch

This function invokes a dispatch, giving redux-thunk knowledge of what to do next

```
export const getAllUsers = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      dispatch({ type: GET_ALL_USER, payload: res.data.data }); // Calling a dispatch, which is a clear trigger for the middleware
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
};
```

## Why is Code #2 not working - Higher scope is not async

You cannot call `await fetchComments` here, because you've never defined `fetchComments` to be async, so redux-thunk does not get what you expect it to get

```
export const fetchComments = () => () => { // This is a plain function, noy an asynchronous one, meaning that the middlware won't get the result it is expecting
  axios
    .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
    .then((res) => {
      return {
        type: FETCH_COMMENTS,
        payload: res.data,
      };
    });
};
```

## Why is Code #3 working - The higher scope is async

This can be called `await fetchComments` because you've defined it in `async () => ...` thus, redux-thunk understands it

```
 export const fetchComments = async() => { // Clearly defined to be async
     let res = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
     return {
         type: FETCH_COMMENTS,
         payload:res.data
       }
   ;
 };
```

So to answer your question, **What is the difference between promise vs async when you use redux-thunk?**

`getAllUsers()` => this will trigger `dispatch({...})` after `Promise` is finished, and thats why it works - nothing specifically to do w/ Promise vs Async

`fetchComments()` => This will return a plain function returning an object, after the Promise is done, something which is not OK for redux-thunk

`async fetchComments()` => This can be properly handled with await to fetch finished result (object), like in the function above, but it can be handled because it is async.

So, the problem is not in Promise vs Async, it is how you call the functions, and define them, you could achieve both with Promise or Async

Comment: Code 2 returns undefined and doesn't dispatch anything when promise is resolved. It is also a curry but no values are curried so not sure why it's defined this way. There is no way `dispatch(fetchComments())` would work with code 3 because it is not a thunk, maybe when you have other middleware installed that can handle actions that are promises but that was not stated in the question.